# Change all of the cell border colors in a GridView to red

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I've tried to change all of the lines vertical and horizontal in my `GridView` from the code behind using the code shown below, but this does not seem to have any effect.

Can anyone offer a solution with the code behind please?

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN.Rows)
{
  foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
  {
    cell.Width = 150;
    cell.Height = 20;
    cell.Attributes.CssStyle["text-align"] = "center";
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try border-style:solid; border-width:1px; along with the color?

Comment: yes using cell.Attributes["style"] = "border-style:solid; border-width:1px;border-color:red;" worked for the cells in the table, but not the header also, basically i wish to color ALL lines that make up the gridview...

Comment: Claudio Redi is right, but it is not recommended to set styles on server side.

Comment: How about cell.BorderColor = Color.Red; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`BorderColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.bordercolor.aspx) property

```
cell.BorderColor = Color.FromName("Red");
```

In any case, I would recommend you to use css classes to apply styles to get a much more flexible UI layout.

Answer (score 1):

As you confirmed the below is working. Great!

```
border-style:solid; border-width:1px;
```

Now for the header `gridview.HeaderRow.Cells[0].CssClass = "something"` . Try this out.

Note - only works if AutogenerateColumns = False, won't work for True(default!)

But as Claudio rightly pointed out, all styles should be a part of a css file & you should access them using css classes[preferably only from UI & not from code behind].

Comment: your resposnse is useful, however i have taken onboard the opinions on using CSS and i agree this is the best way forward.

Answer (score 0):

achieved this using CSS as suggested by @dumass